# Integration of Bessel function including specific rings

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

Now, I am interested in the rings of Bessel function. So, basically, I used cylindrical coordinate to make it easy to figure out rings of Bessel function.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t],r Sin[t], BesselJ[0,r]^2},{r,0,BesselJZero[0,3]},{t,0,2 Pi}}
```

[image]

Here, we assume that we only care the center peak and two rings, and want to get the volume of Bessel function in a region between certain x-axis positions. For example, the volume between x= -12 and x = -5 can be represented by like the red area in the figure below.(feeling frustrated even I am not able to plot the graph properly..) The problem is that the region is not expressed by r and t (angle) in the cylindrical coordinate. So, I can't use triple integration to figure out the volume of that region. I need help to solve it.

Welcome any comments, suggestion and solutions. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Cartesion coordinate and define a region to cut the surface and cut the  domain of integrate.

```
f[x_, y_] := BesselJ[0, r]^2 /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 12], 
   PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All];
reg = ImplicitRegion[x <= -5 && Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 12, {x, y}];
reg // Region
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

> `3.6738`

[image]

[image]